# PHP failed to load on VS CODE

Tags: php, symfony, visual-studio-code

I've been working on some Symfony projects for sometime now, everything going fine until today when [PHP is not responding anymore on VS CODE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/szwFE.png)

This problem seems to only be in VS CODE, as when i look up the version on Windows Terminal, [everything seems fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKnrz.png)

The PHP is set in the Path, and I'm also using WAMP.

I just can't seem to get the issue here, please help, i'm stuck now :/

Comment: I googled the error you showed in your first image, this was the top result, please let me know if it works: https://www.thecodebuzz.com/program-ng-failed-to-run-no-application-is-associated/

Comment: Nope, it didn't, i changed the default shell to "CMD" instead of "Windows PowerShell" on VS until i find a proper solution to fix it

Answer (score 0):

Try Reinstalling VS CODE , Try to change the path in environmental variables or else try to install Sublime Text Text Editor, which is more user friendly

Comment: try uninstalling all the extensions and install it again one by one

Comment: @mishen: I just reinstalled VS Code, the php Path is correct, the issue is still there

Comment: @SantoshDangare But i didn't add any extension lately, this just happened today, i didn't touch any VS code or PHP configuration

Comment: @SantoshDangare I uninstalled VS CODE along with all the extensions, and reinstalled it, issue still there :/